# Magento URL to Home

Tags: magento

Our company's ecommerce shop uses magento application. Everything is going well but there is a strang link to url.

For example, our site is www.example.com. But in google search, there is a www.example.com/home link there. Anyone can tell me where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's come from CMS Page in Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

Use a 301 redirect, rel=canonical or robots.txt.
/home and / pages may be duplicated content.